# How to enable CORS in folder hosted on google drive?

Tags: javascript, cors, google-drive-api

How can CORS be enabled for a folder hosted on Google-drive so that it accepts the image uploaded from other URLs ?
I am trying to create a drop function by which user will be able to drop images from their hard drive and view it on the web-page. When I try to do it right now, it gives mes following error :

Error : 
Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.

Thanks

Comment: Are you storing the data on google drive or do you have the file making the CORS request on google drive?

Comment: you can use the google drive API to build and register an app that will let you do this, but you can't alter existing offerings beyond the provided options.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can convince Google-drive to send custom headers this is **impossible**. You *must* send the right Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy for CORS to work.

Maybe you can upload files via a proxy (ie. a server that you control).